# Python Kivy на других платформах

Tags: python, kivy

Вопрос таков, как написанный код на python kivy запускать на разных платформах?
Или я что-то не так понял?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точно так же, как и код на Python:

- Для Android/iOS есть [Buildozer](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer).
- Чисто для iOS есть [Kivy for iOS](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios).